# Applying CRS to TIFF in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

So I’ve been assembling a mosaic of Landsat imagery in python, and I’ve been able to keep the project as a GeoTIFF all this time, but I need to color correct the imagery now because some of the natural colors look off. My thought was to use Photoshop to do this, but photoshop gets rid of the metadata that makes it a GeoTIFF. Since I know the coordinates of the edges of the mosaic, and I know the original CRS, could I color correct it in photoshop and add the geometry back onto it in QGIS afterward? If so, how could I go about tackling this?

Comment: There is probably on old answer, but you can save the original GeoTIFF tags with https://svn.osgeo.org/metacrs/geotiff/trunk/libgeotiff/docs/listgeo.html and copy them into the edited file with https://svn.osgeo.org/metacrs/geotiff/trunk/libgeotiff/docs/geotifcp.html. If you edit the file with a new GIMP version instead of Photoshop the tags are kept.

Answer (score 1):

If you save your raster with a tfw file, the information will survive photoshop.

Do Raster->Conversion->Translate

Make sure you save your file (not as a temporary layer) and in additional command line parameters, set

-co tfw=yes

Then you will save your file as two files .tif and .tfw. The tfw contains information on where to put the tif in a given CRS. Basically where is the upper left corner, what is the x and y size of the pixels and how is it rotated. When you do the processing in photoshopy, do not change anything related to changing the size or number of pixels (i.e. no cropping or changing of resolution). When you read the tiff back into qgis, you need to tell qgis which crs to use for that file. (Right click - properties set Assigned CRS)

Comment: In case anybody tried this just after I posted, it was a mistake in the initial file, -co tfw=yes is the correct command line parameter

Comment: So I tried to do this with two particular tiles from Indiana in the US, and when I loaded them back in and applied the CRS, it randomly placed the tiles on the map. Aside from creating the .tfw file, I didn't do anything with it, was I supposed to?